# why theft.getTime()[0]="aaa"+theft.getTimie()[0] don't change the value?

Tags: java

```
public class Theft{
  private String[] time =new String[4];
  public String[] getTime() {
    return time = Arrays.copyOf(time, 4);
  }

  public void setTime(String[] time) {
    this.time = time;
  }
}
```

When run

```
Theft theft =new Theft();
theft.getTime()[0]="sss";
theft.getTime()[0]="aaa"+theft.getTime()[0];
System.out.println(theft.getTime()[0]);
```

Why does it print "sss" not "aaasss"? The value seems not changed.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are creating a copy of it each time.

```
public class Theft {
    private String[] time = new String[4];

    public String[] getTime() {
        return time; // Return the time itself, not a copy
    }

    public void setTime(String[] time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

Output: `aaasss`

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
theft.getTime()[0]="aaa"+theft.getTime()[0];
```

has a few things going on at a time. Let's break it down into separate instructions so it's easier to follow:

```
String[] time1 = theft.getTime();
String[] time2 = theft.getTime();
String newValue = "aaa"+time2[0];
time1[0] = newValue;
```

As you can see, the array that gets updated is the `time1` that was already replaced by its copy, `time2`. Therefore the update is effectively discarded.